# Is it possible to handle each element in a variadic macro at compile time in C?

Tags: c, macros, variadic-macros

Is it possible to archieve the following somehow? I am using gcc.

```c
#define foo(argCount, ...)\
    FOR_EACH_IN_VA_ARGS_(argCount, element, __VA_ARGS__)\
    {\
        printf("%u", sizeof(element));\
    }
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Boost.Preprocessor can do that. Use it either directly or as an inspiration.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting resource!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer shows how you can do a foreach macro in the preprocessor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775003/1084774

Applied to your example, the `argCount` argument isn't needed and the stateful version isn't really possible because the preprocessor doesn't have mutable state outside of what's defined and what isn't, but you can have an apply-macro-to-each version:

```
#include "foreach.h" //generated header implementing BX_foreachc
#include <stdio.h>
#define prsz(X) printf("%zu\n", sizeof(X))
#define foo(...) BX_foreach(;,prsz,__VA_ARGS__)

int main(void)
{
    foo(char,short,int,long, long long);
    //expands to  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char)) ; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(short)) ; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int)) ; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long)) ; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long long));

 }
```

(relies on the foreach.h header generated by the script posted in the linked answer)

A much simpler way to do this is via a macro-argument-parametrized list macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRSZ(X) printf("%zu\n", sizeof(X));
#define LIST(_) _(char) _(short) _(int) _(long) _(long long)
int main(void)
{
    LIST(PRSZ)
}
```

Either method is portable.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was searching for.

Comment: What does "BX" stand for?

Comment: @DanielSchreiberMendes I quickly plucked it out of my software package, which is namespaced to BX/bx. I could have removed it or renamed it.

Comment: Ah okay. Is there a possibility to pass two arguments to PRSZ ?

Comment: @DanielSchreiberMendes No. You can embed the second argument in the PRSZ macro, or you can group tuples in parantheses so they're just one argument.

Answer (score 0):

If argCount is a constant it could be imitated, otherwise, you will need support for some contemporary standard.

Comment: Yes, argCount is a compile-time constant. What would the imitation look like?

Comment: @DanielSchreiberMendes Just use pretty long #if #elif #else chain.

Comment: Could you maybe explain that a bit further? I do not understand in which way this could be done.